# postrgesql function to modify another table if changes occur in one of the tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a trigger that executes a function "modification_function( )" so that when inserting, deleting or updating each row of the "People" table, the function has to insert or update the information needed by the "People_info" table, or delete it in case it has been deleted from the "People" table.
In order to do any action on the "People_info" table, the function will get all the necessary information from the tables: "People", "Employment" and "Country".

In addition, the varchar attribute 'experience' of the table 'People_info' must store the non-null value of one of the following two attributes of the 'people' table:
The value of the 'age' attribute or
The value of the attribute 'Date of birth'.

'Age' is integer and 'Date of birth' is type date. Therefore, since 'experience' is varchar I must modify the typology of this data using 'to_char'.

In fact I think that to store the non-null value of one of these attributes, an if must be done so that if 'age' IS NULL : experience= date of birth, ELSE experience=age.

The minimum wage attribute of info_persons must contain the values of the salary attribute of the employment table.

I have set up the scheme as follows but I am very blocked when it comes to putting these requirements in the code.  I appreciate any proposal to implement it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION modification_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP='UPDATE') THEN
        UPDATE PEOPLE_INFO 
        name =NEW.people.name
        id_employee =NEW.employment.id_employee
        current employment= NEW.employment.current_employment
        minimum_wage= NEW.employment.salary
        country_id=NEW.country.country_id
        street=NEW.country.street

      
        RETURN NEW;
   IF (TG_OP='INSERT') THEN


    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';  
    
CREATE TRIGGER trigger
AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE OR INSERT ON people
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE modification_function();
```

```
TABLE PEOPLE:
name  PRIMARY KEY
age
date of birth
level of studies

EMPLOYMENT TABLE
id_employee PRIMARY KEY
current_employment 
HEADQUARTERS
salary
seniority

COUNTRY TABLE
country_id PRIMARY KEY
street
zip/postal code


PEOPLE_INFO TABLE
name PRIMARY KEY
id_employee PRIMARY KEY
current_employment
minimum_wage
country_id
street
experience
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should read about normalization. Your current design is just terrible with redundancies/dependencies everywhere. Normalize that design and then use *views* to have the data joined/aggregated. You already shot yourself in the foot and are aiming another 12-pounder at it...

Comment: Well, that is the reason why I have posted the question here, so that whoever wants to and can, can propose their points of view. This is supposed to be a space to contribute

Comment: "This is supposed to be a space to contribute" -- So I did. Again, I contribute by advising you to familiarize yourself with normalization and work this completely over. It would be too much for SO's concept of concise Q&A to work all of this through with you.

Comment: As stated by @sticky bit, your data model sounds like strange and improvable : (a) age should not be stored as a column but should be calculated at the run time with the `age()` function (b) Why do you need to duplicate data from table PEOPLE, EMPLOYEE, COUNTRY into table PEOPLE_INFO ? (c) Should a new row insert in PEOPLE_INFO be triggered from anyone of table PEOPLE, EMPLOYEE, COUNTRY ? I suggest you to first share your data model definition in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) so that we can help working on it before looking at the triggers definition.